# package php as an android application?

Tags: php, android, web-applications, package

I'm developing an Android app, and due to time circumstances, I started developing the project in **PHP**, together with a **MySQL** backend. is it possible to package `the project folder` as a **APK** where it could be opened within the tablet?

I understand Android applications are meant to be written in **Java**, and I have checked out:

http://phpforandroid.net/

But it doesn't answer if it was possible to package a complete PHP project as an APK.

Comment: That would mean you'd need to run a web server and a MySQL server on the phone/tablet and run the app through a browser. Even if that's possible, it'll be a terrible experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since PHP is a server side language you would have to run a webserver ***and*** a MySQL server on the device (like @deceze said).

Since you have already started development in PHP my recommendation would be to develop a web based application and have your users access it from a very lightweight client on the Android device. You could use something like [**PhoneGap**](http://phonegap.com/) or [**AppCelerator**](http://www.appcelerator.com) to develop a front end client app since I'm guessing your talents lie in web development :)

Comment: correct, thanks for the input :) always nice to know there are people out there to help upcoming (albeit slowly upcoming) developers!

Answer (score 1):

"When all you have is a hammer, you start to approach every problem as if it was a nail"

You're using the wrong tool for the job.  PHP is not meant for writing interactive GUI applications, it's meant for running server side scripts or commandline scripts.  Even if you could easily run PHP on an android phone (which you cant), it would be the wrong choice of language for a phone app.

You have two options

1) throw away the work you've done so far and redo it in a language more appropriate to the task at hand

2) deploy your application to a publicly accessible web server and run it via the handset's web browser.

If you think about it, you'd need to squeeze a web server, the PHP core, whatever extensions your application uses and a MySQL server onto a handheld device.  This is seriously overkill.

And why MySQL?  Android provides SQLite database support.

Comment: correct, thanks for the input :) always nice to know there are people out there to help upcoming (albeit slowly upcoming) developers!